# Cómo puedo convertir una propiedad de un objeto en un array

Tags: javascript, array, javascript-objeto, ecmascript-6, jsonobject

Tengo este objeto y necesito obtener de él 3 arrays.

Uno con los date: ['2020-01', '2020-02']

otro con los sum_presipitacion: ['0.00', '99.60']

y otro con los precipitacion_acumulado: [null, '99.60']

Pero no se pueden acceder con el nombre de las propiedades porque estas pueden cambiar en un futuro. (Es decir no se puede hacer result.indicator.precipitation sino que debe deconstruirse de una manera distinta el objeto)

```js
const result = [
    {
        "date": "2020-01",
        "indicator": {
            "precipitation": {
                "sum_precipitacion": "0.00"
            },
            "cumulativePrecipitation": {
                "precipitacion_acumulado": null
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-02",
        "indicator": {
            "precipitation": {
                "sum_precipitacion": "99.60"
            },
            "cumulativePrecipitation": {
                "precipitacion_acumulado": "99.60"
            }
        }
    }
]

/* ------- Así he intentado deconstuirlo. -------------------- */

var dates = []
var values = []
var temp = []

result.map(r => {
    dates.push(Object.values(r)[0])
    temp.push(Object.values(r)[1])
})

temp.map(t => {
    let obj = Object.values(t)
    obj.map(({sum_precipitacion}) => {
        values.push(sum_precipitacion)
    })
})

console.log(values)
```

Comment: `Pero no se pueden acceder con el nombre de las propiedades porque estas pueden cambiar`... Basado en tu ejemplo, cuales son las propiedades que pueden cambiar en el futuro?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer algo así, esto funcionaría sin importar el nombre de las propiedades siempre que se mantenga la estructura. La otra opción podría ser obtener las keys e ir ingresando luego con las keys variables a cada nivel.

```
    const result = [
  {
    date: "2020-01",
    indicator: {
      precipitation: {
        sum_precipitacion: "0.00",
      },
      cumulativePrecipitation: {
        precipitacion_acumulado: null,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    date: "2020-02",
    indicator: {
      precipitation: {
        sum_precipitacion: "99.60",
      },
      cumulativePrecipitation: {
        precipitacion_acumulado: "99.60",
      },
    },
  },
];


const dates = [];
const aValues = [];
const bValues = [];

result.map((r) => {
  const nivel1 = Object.values(r);
  const nivel2 = Object.values(nivel1[1]);
  const nivel3A = Object.values(nivel2[0]);
  const nivel3B = Object.values(nivel2[1]);
  dates.push(nivel1[0]);
  aValues.push(nivel3A[0]);
  bValues.push(nivel3B[0]);
});

console.log(dates);
console.log(aValues);
console.log(bValues);
```